# Find matrix representation of following linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider subspace $V=span\{f_1,f_2\}$ of the complex vector space of complex valued functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$, where $f_1(x)=\cos x $ and $f_2(x)=\sin x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. $D: V \to V$ is a linear operator defines as the derivative $D(g)=g'$ for any function $g \in V$

1. Find the matrix representation of D with respect to the ordered basis $\{f_1,f_2\}$
2. Find the matrix representation of the vector $h$ with respect to the ordered basis $\{f_1,f_2\}$ where $h(x)=3e^{ix}-2e^{-ix}, \:$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
3. Calculate derivative of $h(x)=3e^{ix}-2e^{-ix}$ using the matrix representations you have found in parts 1 and 2.

This is an exercise in my book.

My thoughts:

**For $1$:**
$V=span(\cos x, \sin x)=a \cos x+b \sin x,$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

So this gives:

$D(span(\cos x, \sin x))=D(a \cos x+b \sin x)=(a \cos x+b \sin x)'=- a\sin x + b \cos x = (- a)(\sin x) + (b )(\cos x ) = \begin{bmatrix} - a\\ b \end{bmatrix}$

I am not sure whether it is correct or not. If I could do first part this might give me some idea about part 2 and 3.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix isn't correct. Remember, if you're representing a linear transformation as a matrix, the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors under the linear transformation. The derivative of the span is a vector - there's no reason that should be the correct matrix.

The correct approach here is to determine $D(\cos(x))$ as a vector $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$, and $D(\sin(x))$ as a vector $\begin{bmatrix}c \\ d \end{bmatrix}$, then you have $D = \begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$. This is the definition of representing the linear transformation as a matrix. Once you have that, for part (b) and (c), recall that $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, and they should follow quickly.

Comment: Can you please explain how you get $D(\cos x)=\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$ ??
So as you said the matrix representation of $D$ is $D = \begin{pmatrix}a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$

For vector $h$ $$D(3e^{ix}-2e^{-ix})= D(3 \cos x+3i \sin  x-2\cos x +2i\sin x) = D(\cos x+ 5i \sin x)$$ I think it is correct so far.  
$$D(\cos x+ 5i \sin x)=D(\cos x)+ 5i \:D(\sin x)=\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}+ 5i \: \begin{pmatrix}  c  \\ d  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}+   \begin{pmatrix}  5ic  \\ 5id  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}  a+5ic  \\ a+5id  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So This is matrix representation of vector $h$. I am not sure whether its correct or not.

Can you please give some hint about part 3?

Comment: Can you please explain how you get $D(\cos x)=\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$ ?? Ok I understand it how you got this. Could you please check part 2 which I wrote above and give some hint about part3

Comment: Also in your answer I think $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers. Right?

Comment: $D(\cos x)=\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$

For this part I think what did is:
$$D(\cos x)=a\cos x +b \sin x =\begin{pmatrix}a  \\ b  \end{pmatrix}$$ Is this correct ?

Comment: To be clear, $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers you need to explicitly find. Your matrix should have no variables. The $a, b$ I used are unrelated to the span you wrote in your question. You should find explicit numerical values. What is the derivative of $\cos(x)$? Write that in terms of the basis, that's your first vector/the first column of your matrix. What is the derivative of $\sin(x)$? Write that in terms of your basis, that's the second column of your matrix

Comment: I think this is how we can find derivative of $\cos x$, $\sin x$ and write it in terms of the basis. 
$$D(\cos x)=0\cos x + (-1) \sin x =\begin{pmatrix}0  \\ -1  \end{pmatrix}$$ $$D(\sin)=(1)\cos x + (0) \sin x =\begin{pmatrix}1  \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: If this is correct than Matrix representation of D is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 &1  \\ -1&0  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: If this matrix representation is correct than for vector $h$ $$D(3e^{ix}-2e^{-ix}) = \begin{pmatrix}5i  \\ -1  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: For part 3, I think if we use part 2 than the derivative of vector $h$ is $$5i \cos x -\sin x$$

Comment: Your vector is correct. What I don't understand is why you've taken the derivative of $h$ to find it as a vector. To find $h$, you just need to write it in terms of the basis vectors, and put those in a column vector. $h = 3e^{ix} - 2e^{-ix} = 3\cos(x) + 3i\sin(x) - 2\cos(-x) - 2i\sin(-x) = \cos(x) + 5i\sin(x)$, so the vector is $h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 5i \end{pmatrix}$. Then, for part (c), multiply this vector by the derivative matrix.

Comment: You seem to have some pretty fundamental misunderstanding about linear transformations and representing transformations/vectors in terms of a basis. I would strongly recommend you review that part of your book before doing further exercises.